# eslint watch task running repeatedly

Tags: javascript, node.js, watch, eslint, package.json

I am trying to lint my files with eslint on file change using `npm scripts`:

```
"scripts": {                                                                   
  "lint": "eslint ./* lib",                                                    
  "lint:watch":"watch 'npm run lint' .",                                       
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"                        
}
```

I use the [watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/watch) package to accomplish this.

I find that the watch task runs infinitely in a loop. Does eslint write to a file in the app's root directory. If so, how can I teach watch to ignore the changes made by `eslint`.

My `.eslintrc`, if nessecary:

```
{                                                                                
   "parser":"babel-eslint",                                                        
   "extends":"eslint:recommended",                                                 
   "rules":{                                                                       
      "strict":2,                                                                  
      "no-var":2,                                                                  
      "prefer-template":2,                                                         
      "prefer-arrow-callback":1,                                                   
      "prefer-rest-params":2,                                                      
      "prefer-spread":2,                                                           
      "object-shorthand":1,                                                        
      "no-duplicate-imports":2,                                                    
      "no-confusing-arrow":2,                                                      
      "comma-dangle":0                                                             
    }                                                                              
 }
```

Comment: to quickly disable a file just put this line at the top: `/* eslint-disable */`

Comment: @Omarjmh I think there was a miscommunication, I run a package called `watch` on `eslint`, this package is watching for files in the project's root directory, when eslint runs it seems to write to a folder on the `root directory` causing watch to detect changes which runs eslint again. If I know which file, I can ask `watch` to ignore it.

Answer (score 6):

You can tell ESLint to ignore specific files and directories by creating an `.eslintignore` file in your project’s root directory. This is what one looks like:

It is plain text, simply add a `.eslintignore` file to your project and write the files you don't want 'watched'

The following will ignore all JS files:

```
**/*.js
```

You can get specific or use a glob pattern like the above to ignore all files of a certain type.

[Relevant Docs](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#ignoring-files-and-directories)